# Not able to login via Sitecore identity Server in Sitecore 10.1

Tags: identity-server

We have set up Sitecore 10 environment. It was working properly but suddenly it stopped authenticating and started giving error.

We are getting below error everytime we try to log in

> Login failed for user 'securityuser'

is there anything we need to check in Sitecore Core DB for this user?

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: it looks like your securityuser is not able to login into database, could you please check your connection string and make sure the password for securityuser is working fine?

Comment: Or try to change user name as "sa" and the password, it should work

Comment: perfect both the solution worked. Problem is with securityuser. Not sure what has happened to the user account. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following things, to make it work.

1. Update your password: Using the `SQL management studio` you will need to connect to the database server and then run the below command to modify the password.

   `ALTER USER securityuser WITH PASSWORD = 'your-password'`
2. Add role to a user: You need to execute `sp_addrolemember` procedure with 'db_owner' and 'securityuser' parameters like that:

   `EXEC sp_addrolemember 'db_owner', 'masteruser'`

Either of the ones might resolve your issue.